# Implicit type conversion failed to compile, why is that?

Tags: c++, string, templates, implicit

I wrote a small code:

```
#include<type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct M{
    /*explicit*/ M(const T*) {}
};

template<typename T>
M<T> f(const M<T>&) {return M<T>();}

int main() {
    M<char> s1 = f<char>("Hello"); // OK
    M<char> s2 = f("Hello"); // error
    M<char> s3 = f(decay<char*>("Hello")); // error
    return 0;
}
```

Well the first `s1` successfully compiles, although if I change `M::M` to explicit, it will also fail. But `s2` and `s3` fail to compile, even when I use `decay<char*>` on `s3`.

---

The difference is whether I specified template initialization argument type for `f` or not. Why do `s2` and `s3` fail to compile, any principles behind this in the C++ standard?

If I change main function to like this:

```
int main()
{
    M<char> s1=f<char>("Hello");//OK
    const char* p="hello";
    M<char> s2=f(p);//error
    M<char> s3=f(decay<const char*>("Hello"));//error
    return 0;
}
```

It still fails.

Why?

Comment: Try to put yourself in the compiler's shoes. Explain how, in `s2` case, given the function parameter being `const char[6]` the compiler can conclude that the template parameter must be `char`. P.S. Your decay is wrong. `const char[6]` decays to `const char *`, and not `char *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [template type argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions) does not consider implicit conversions.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

For the 2nd case, compiler can't match `M<T>` with `const char [6]`, the function template is just ignored before overload resolution.

The 3rd case fails because `"Hello"` (i.e. `const char [6]`) can't be converted to `decay<char *>`. You might mean `typename decay<char*>::type`, but it still won't compile for the same reason of the 2nd case.

Comment: If "T" means any type, why M<T> cannot match T to "const char [6]"?

Comment: @HindForsum `T` can match, but the parameter type is `M<T>`, which can't match.